# MOD_REWRITE but not in sub directories

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following HTACCESS code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase   /

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/cms/|/js/|/mobile/)* [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /page.php [L]
```

As it stands, it works as I need it to within the root of the site, but accessing an admin page (`/cms/`), I can tell via PhpConsole that it is still hitting page.php. I think this is because the admin is controlled with a query string: URIs look like `/cms/?view=pages&action=edit&id=4`

If I uncomment the first condition, this problem no longer occurs, but my front end comes back with a 404 on files that don't exist, rather than redirecting to page.php

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code with this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule (?!^(cms|js|mobile)(/.*|)$)^.*$ page.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: Do you mean a URI of `/cms/style.css` is still going to `page.php`?

Comment: Actually no, that works fine. When I navigate to /cms/?view=pages it is still hitting page.php. I am putting in code on page.php to die() if it detects the /cms/, but I'd rather not have to.

Comment: Even that is weird. As per above regex any URI that starts with `/cms/` should not be forwarded to `page.php`. Even in my testing `/cms/?view=pages` doesn't get redirected to `page.php`.

Comment: Could your URI be by any chance `/cms?view=pages` (without trailing slash)?

Comment: "Could your URI be by any chance /cms?view=pages (without trailing slash)?" No. I tried your revised Rule and it works perfectly! Going to try and break it now ;)